# How do I read a value from registry?

Tags: c#, registry

I want to read the port number for remote desktops, but it doesn't work.

[MSDN states](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759) that it is at

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber

which is a key that exists in my registry on Windows 8.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtPort.Text = (string) Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp", "PortNumber", "");
}
```

The string returned is null.

**Correct answer:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtPort.Text = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\", "PortNumber", -1).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the actual registry to see whether there's a value there?

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio with a user that has rights to check the registry ? try runnin VS as Administrator

Comment: I did check the registry, but not for spaces. My mistake.

Comment: I did run as administrator just to be sure, because I read that writing to the registry requires this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a space in "Terminal Server":

```
@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp"
                                                              ↑
```

Comment: And it's an int, not a string.

Comment: @JonSkeet, He's just showing that on a textfield right ? So does it matter ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Yes, it matters. He's *casting* to `string`, which will fail when the value returned is a boxed `int`.

Comment: Thanks. My programming world falls apart when copy/paste doesn't work

Comment: @KasperHansen: The natural thing to do when diagnosing this is just to run regedit and validate it for yourself. (That's what I did, and was about to post a similar answer when I saw that dtb had already done so.)